# How should I separate my single js file into logic , presenter and css file?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm quite new to React native and studying it with online tutorials

Here my one of main js file named RequestScreen (js file) contains every whole code(logic, presentation, css parts)

I'm trying to create RequestScreen folder with 4 js files( container.js, index.js, presenter.js and styles.js) instead of one single whole code.

However, I'm stuck with separation processing.

Could you help me to divide my react code below into 4 separated files for better design structure?

any good example for me?

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import Text from '../components/Text'; //Customized Text component
import NumberPad from '../components/NumberPad';  //Customized NumPad component

const SendRequestScreen = ( {navigation} ) => {
    
    
    //*********Logic Parts it has to be moved to container.js
    ///////////
    ///////////
    const [amount, setAmount] = useState("0");

    const convertToDollars = (currentAmount) => {
        const newAmount = currentAmount / 100;
        return newAmount.toLocaleString("en-US", { style: "currency", currency: "USD"});
    };

    const pressKey = (item, index) => {
        setAmount((prev) => {
            return index != 10 ? prev + item : prev.slice(0, prev.length - 1);
        });
    };

    //*********Presentation parts it has to be moved to presenter.js
    ///////////
    ///////////
    return (
        <Container>
            <Text center large heavy margin="16px 0 0 0">
                Send
            </Text>

            <Amount>
                <Text title heavy>
                    {convertToDollars(amount)}
                </Text>
                <Text bold color="#727479">
                    Choose amount to send
                </Text>
            </Amount>

            <User>
                <ProfilePhoto source={require("../assets/images/test.png")} />
                <UserDetails>
                    <Text medium heavy>
                        Jin
                    </Text>
                </UserDetails>
                <LogOut onLongPress={() => navigation.navigate("Touch")} delayPressIn={0}>
                <Text >Log Out</Text>
                </LogOut>
            </User>

            <Send>
                <Text medium heavy>
                    Send {convertToDollars(amount)} to Jin
                </Text>
            </Send>

            <NumberPad onPress={pressKey} />
        </Container>
        
    )
}

 //*********CSS parts it has to be moved to styles.js
 ///////////
 ///////////
const LogOut = styled.TouchableOpacity`
    width: 54px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-right: 12px;
    background-color: #5196f4;
    border-radius: 4px;
`

const Container = styled.SafeAreaView`
    flex: 1;
    background-color: #1e1e1e;
`

const Amount = styled.View`
    margin-top: 64px;
    align-items: center;
`;

const User = styled.View`
    margin: 32px 16px;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
`;

const ProfilePhoto = styled.Image`
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    border-radius: 12px;
`;

const UserDetails = styled.View`
    flex: 1;
    margin: 0 16px;
`;

const Send = styled.TouchableOpacity`
    margin: 16px;
    background-color: #5196f4;
    padding: 16px 32px;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 12px;
`;

const StatusBar = styled.StatusBar``;


export default SendRequestScreen;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy. you can export your StyledComponents like mylist-styling.js

```
// mylist-styling.js
export const LogOut = styled.TouchableOpacity`
    width: 54px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-right: 12px;
    background-color: #5196f4;
    border-radius: 4px;
`
.....
```

Usage in SendRequestScreen.js

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { LogOut } from './myList-styling'; // here is usage

const SendRequestScreen = ( {navigation} ) => {

    ....

    // use here
    return (
        .....
        <LogOut onLongPress={() => navigation.navigate("Touch")} delayPressIn={0}>
            <Text >Log Out</Text>
        </LogOut>
        
    )
}
```

> Not essential to use container.js as you can write login part in SendRequestScreen.js and you can use presenter to write common logic there if you want

Answer (score 0):

I worked on many projects and I think you should do something like this.

Like you have screen settings.

1. Create a directory name `Settings` and create `index.js` file
2. In the same directory you can create styles.js (Or in case of multiple screens you can create directory styles with multiple files in it) In this file you can write all your css.
3. And for View part (Presenter) create new file SettingsView.js a HOC you just need to write all your viewable part in this file and all the functionality and data pass throw props in this file form index.js and you need to import your css file in this file.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to structure it like below. Also no offence you can implement basic logics into screen but if you want them to be reusable on other screens than have a Util folder for it. In your case put **convertToDollars** function in Util.js and get yourself out of worries to implement it everywhere. Will be more helpful if are there many hands touching your code.

```js
|— src
|   |— assets
|   |   |— fonts
|   |   |— images
|   |— screens
|   |   |— login
|   |   |   |— index.js
|   |   |   |— styles.js
|   |   |— signup
|   |   |   |— index.js
|   |   |   |— styles.js
|   |— utils
|   |   |— Util.js
|   |   |— DataHandler.js
```